# Getting ERROR_TIMEOUT(Connection timed out) in onReceivedError WebviewClient after setting different proxy. Mostly occuring in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-webview

My app works with proxy ip's. I request proxy ip from our php. and i will use it for webview. I was getting ERROR_TIMEOUT, errorcode-8 ,(connection timed out). within few seconds. Does it have to do with proxy settings. if yes please tell me how to set proxy for lollipop and above. It works fine some times but gets this error most.

Comment: Have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ` in manifest?

Comment: yes. i have added it.